# when going from excel to R, dropping a 0 from the beginning of a number. How do i keep this from happening?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a series of zip codes that are stored in excel (not my choice), that I need to import into R, but to retain the ability to used a matching function i need the "0" that starts off the majority of these zipcodes. How do I keep them R from dropping the 0 when reading the csv?

Comment: You can read them as `character`. E.g.: `read.csv(header=FALSE, text="0241,0018", colClasses="character")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These data are saved as a `.csv` file, but if you want to reproduce it, you will have to run these first lines:

```
    ZIP<-structure(list(V1 = c("08979", "67689", "06978", "54823")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

write.csv(ZIP, "Zips.csv")
```

If you read in without any options

```
ZIP<-read.csv("Zips.csv",header=F)
head(ZIP)
     V1
1  8979
2 67689
3  6978
4 54823
```

You are missing zeros in front, because R is assuming the class is integer or numeric, so a zero in the front is meaningless. However if you set `colClasses = "character"`, you can avoid this:

```
ZIP<-read.csv("Zips.csv",header=F, colClasses="character")

head(ZIP)
 V1
1 08979
2 67689
3 06978
4 54823
```

It also works as factor:

```
ZIP<-read.csv("Zips.csv",header=F, colClasses="factor")
head(ZIP)
     V1
1 08979
2 67689
3 06978
4 54823
```